# Text join with criteria in excel 2019

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I have this data at A,B column and formula at C column
[image: Like this]

I tried with formula at C2 cell:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$2:$B$13=$B2,IF(MATCH($A$2:$A$13&$B$2:$B$13,$A$2:$A$13&$B$2:$B$13,0)=ROW($A$2:$A$13)-ROW($A$2)+1,$A$2:$A$13,""),""))}
```

However, that result is not what I want.

I expect result at C2 =`Jame, Mike, Jame, Joo`

It means I wish to have formula to joint text with criteria and ignore duplicates next cell.
Thankyou

Comment: Excel 2016, let alone Excel 2010, does not have a function called `TEXTJOIN()` unless you are using a UDF?

Comment: @JvdV, Sorry I mistake version of MS Excel. I just correct it

Answer (score 1):

If this was Excel 365, you would use `UNIQUE` and `FILTER`.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A13, B2:B13="A")))
```

In Excel 2019, you need to create a helper column in column `C` and column `D`. Column `C` needs formulas like `=IF(B2="A",A2,"")` and column `D` needs formulas like `=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:$C2,"="&C2)=1,C2,"")`. Lastly in column `E` use `{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,D2:D13)}`.

Edit: Fixed my formula. It should reference `$C$2:$C2` not `$C$2:$C$2`.

Comment: I tried It didn't work for me. I do not want `B2="A"` . That's hard code with particular `A`

Comment: @Parabol, I fixed my formula. It should reference `$C$2:$C2` not `$C$2:$C$2`.

Comment: Sorry, result is `Jame, Mike, Jame, Joo` While I expect `Jame, Mike, Jame, Joo` as my question